# I want to create a custom tab on product view page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, product-view

I want to  create a custom tab on product view page in `Magento 2`

and inside that tab I want call `phtml` files of another modules

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.information.tab" as="productinformation" 
        template="product/view/product_details.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Details</argument>
        </arguments>
        <container name="vendor.profile.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="vendor-profile-container">
            <container name="vendor.profile.logo.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-3 vendor-profile-logo">
                <block class="Vnecoms\Vendors\Block\Profile\Logo" name="vendor.profile.logo" template="Vnecoms_Vendors::profile/logo.phtml" />
            </container>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Did you get a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new tab in the product detail page is very easy. Below are the steps:

**Step 1:** Create file **`catalog_product_view.xml`** in the **app/design/frontend/{Namespace}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/layout** folder and write below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Vnecoms\Vendors\Block\Profile\Logo" name="vendor.profile.logo" template="Vnecoms_Vendors::profile/logo.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Tab Label</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 2:** Create the file **`logo.phtml`** in the path **app/design/frontend/{Namespace}/{themename}/Vnecoms_Vendors/templates/profile** and add the content you like.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your `block` and `container` closing in your XML

I updated the `xml` and added proper `block` and container closing

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.information.tab" as="productinformation" 
           template="product/view/product_details.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
       <arguments>
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Details</argument>
       </arguments>
       <container name="vendor.profile.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="vendor-profile-container">
        <container name="vendor.profile.logo.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-3 vendor-profile-logo">
            <block class="Vnecoms\Vendors\Block\Profile\Logo" name="vendor.profile.logo" template="Vnecoms_Vendors::profile/logo.phtml" />
        </container>
       </container>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```